# php server could not find driver

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up the internal php server.  When I run it I get the following message:

```
Fatal error: could not find driver in 
E:\webProjects\skipper\drydockx\includes\functions.php on line 50
```

line 50 of the functions.php file: (at the bottom)

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{
    // SQL statement
    $sql = func_get_arg(0); 

    // parameters, if any
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);  

    // try to connect to database
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            // connect to database
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);  //LINE 50
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is `new PDO("mysql:dbname="...)`, do you have a mysql driver installed/enabled ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a module called `pdo_mysql`. Looking for following in `phpinfo()`

```
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version => 5.1.44
```

In Ubuntu/Debian you can use:

PHP5: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

PHP7: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

for Windows 8.1/10 in :\php.ini file you should uncomment line "extension=pdo_mysql"